# How to add a tooltip to a TableView header cell in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

Does anyone know how to add a tooltip to a column header in a [TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) ?

There are many places where are explained how to add the tooltip to data cells, but I didn't find a way to add the tooltip to header.

Using the tool [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), I can see that the headers are Labels inside a TableColumnHeader object, but It seems that It is not a public object.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>();
    Label firstNameLabel = new Label("First Name");
    firstNameLabel.setTooltip(new Tooltip("This column shows the first name"));
    firstNameCol.setGraphic(firstNameLabel);
```

Comment: It works ! I need to remove the TableColumn text property, but I get what I need, thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Note that if you have `tableMenuButtonVisible` set to true and use this solution, the menu shown by that button won't contain any text as it uses the text of the table columns.

Comment: Thanks James_D! I found that if you wrap your code in a `Platform.runLater(() -> {}` you can just `.lookup()` the header and its existing label. Thanks for helping me figure it all out!

Comment: It seems like this removed the auto column width that was present, is there a way to restore it?

Answer (score 10):

This is an extended answer to James_D. (I don't have the reputation to comment):

To make the label connect with textProperty of the column and just hide the original text, so it does not mess up the rest of the table functionality:

```
nameLabel.textProperty().bindBidirectional(textProperty());
nameLabel.getStyleClass().add("column-header-label");
nameLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE); //Makes it take up the full width of the table column header and tooltip is shown more easily.
```

css:

```
.table-view .column-header .label{
    -fx-content-display: graphic-only;
}
.table-view .column-header .label .column-header-label{
    -fx-content-display: text-only;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `setMaxWidth()`, the tooltips are shown much more naturally for the user (when hovering any part of the header, not necessarily the exact text part per se)

Comment: I found that `label.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);` works a treat; the tooltip appears in the whole square, not just on the same line as the text!

Comment: The style classes may be simplified by using a nested Label selector (that way no id has to be set). e.i.: _grahpics-only selector_: `.column-header Label` _text-only selector_: `.column-header Label Label`

Answer (score 5):

### The solution

Alternatively, you can look up the label that's already there and just give it a tool tip.

In order to `.lookup()` an element the table needs to be rendered already. To be sure that your code runs after the table is rendered, just wrap your code in a `Platform.runlater()`.

```
// We need to do this after the table has been rendered (we can't look up elements until then)
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    // Prepare a tooltip
    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("This is a super cool control; here's how to work it...");
    tooltip.setWrapText(true);
    tooltip.setMaxWidth(200);

    // Get column's column header
    TableColumnHeader header = (TableColumnHeader) historyTable.lookup("#" + column.getId());

    // Get column header's (untooltipped) label
    Label label = (Label) header.lookup(".label");

    // Give the label a tooltip
    label.setTooltip(tooltip);

    // Makes the tooltip display, no matter where the mouse is inside the column header.
    label.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

---

### The solution at scale

If you want to do this for your whole set of columns, you might put them all in a LinkedHashMap (this will just help you organizationally by keeping your columns associated with their messages):

```
// We'll use this to associate columns with messages for right now.
LinkedHashMap<TableColumn<Person, String>, String> tableColumns = new LinkedHashMap<>();

// Each column gets a helpful message
tableColumns.put(numberOfBoxesColumn, "The total number of boxes that have arrived");
tableColumns.put(backordersColumn, "Use these columns as a measure of how urgently the Purchase Order needs to be processed.");
/*... put each column in along with it's message */
```

... then use a for-each loop to loop through and give each column a tooltip ...

```
// Make a tooltip out of each message. Give each column('s label) it's tooltip.
for (Map.Entry<TableColumn<Person, String>, String> pair : tableColumns.entrySet()) {
    
    TableColumn<Person, String> column;
    String message;

    // Get the column and message
    column = pair.getKey();
    message = pair.getValue();

    // Prepare a tooltip
    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip(message);
    tooltip.setWrapText(true);
    tooltip.setMaxWidth(200);

    // Get column's column header
    TableColumnHeader header = (TableColumnHeader) historyTable.lookup("#" + column.getId());

    // Get column header's (untooltipped) label
    Label label = (Label) header.lookup(".label");

    // Give the label a tooltip
    label.setTooltip(tooltip);

    // Makes the tooltip display, no matter where the mouse is inside the column header.
    label.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

---

NOTE: I tried the combination of Jesper and James' solutions before coming up with this one. Sadly, when I did, **the CSS caused all of my labels to disappear** when I look at my `.fxml` layout in SceneBuilder. And we just can't have that, can we? (okay *maybe I* just couldn't have that).

[image: Where're mah labels!]