# Set tooltip on TableColumn(JavaFX) without side effect

Tags: java, javafx

There is a way to set tooltip like that

```
if (tooltipText != null) {
    Label lb = new Label(column.getText());
    lb.setTooltip(new Tooltip(tooltipText));
    column.setText(null);
    column.setGraphic(lb);
}
```

Unfortunately then will be exists ugly side-effect.

[image: Empty names in table's menu]

We set null to text of column but menuItems invoke column.getText(). If we don't do this, there will be double name in header.How to solve it? Suppose by means of css..

This answer doesn't erase side-effect
[How to add a tooltip to a TableView header cell in JavaFX 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224826/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-tableview-header-cell-in-javafx-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The following code relies on internals of the `TableView` skin. These could be subject to change, since they reside in the `com.sun` packages.

CSS lookup can be used to get access to the `TableColumnHeader` nodes after the first layout pass on the `TableView`. Those can be used to retrieve the `Label` that is used to display the `TableColumn`'s `text` property.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView tv = createTableView();

    Scene scene = new Scene(tv);
    
    // generate layout pass
    tv.applyCss();
    tv.layout();

    // assign tooltips to headers
    tv.lookupAll(".column-header").stream().forEach(n -> {
        TableColumnHeader header = (TableColumnHeader) n;
        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("Tooltip: " + header.getTableColumn().getText());
        ((Control) header.lookup(".label")).setTooltip(tooltip);
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```